# Случайно открыл файл .ui через блокнот

Tags: python, ui, qt-designer

Из любопытства, я случайно открыл файл .ui, через блокнот, и теперь не знаю как вернуть все обратно, подскажите как это исправить. Уже несколько дней не могу решить эту проблему Буду очень благодарен! Сброс настроек не работает

Comment: Закрыть блокнот?

Comment: так в чём суть проблемы ?

Comment: assoc...........

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу его скомпилировать в py файл

Answer (score 3):

1)Параметры» (клавиши Win+I) — Система — Приложения по умолчанию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сброс не помогает: (